# tensorflow computation time keeps increasing every 20k steps

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I noticed that during training, tensorflow keeps getting slower. I plotted the computation time per sample during training and I observe that after a first 80k of being roughly constant, it keeps increasing; what's more, it seems to follow a pattern where the computation times bumps every 20k steps and remain constant in-between.

[image: computation time]

After 400k steps, computation times grew from 1.46 to 25.11ms per sample, a x17 increase that is clearly not welcome.

When I stop training, and resume from the last saved model, computation time per sample drops back to ~1.46 ms, so this does not come from the model.

Has somebody experienced the same problem, and what was the cause? (My next step will be to run without saving summaries to try to locate the problem at this level).

**Update**: when summaries are off the computation time stays flat.

**Update**: no error thrown with summaries on and `tf.get_default_graph().finalize()` called before the training loop.

**Update** and partial answer.

It seems the inflation in the computation time is due to using a `trace_level` with a value of `tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE` when evaluating my summaries.

Replacing

```
run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
smry = sess.run(smry_op, feed_dict=feed_dict, options=run_options)
```

with

```
smry = sess.run(smry_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

gets rid of the problem. Of course the question remains why FULL_TRACE would produce such a growing overhead, therefore I leave the question open.

Comment: Please update if you narrow this down

Comment: Maybe you're saving the modelweights every 20.000 steps and have a memory leak each time you do that?

Comment: I do save models, but every 1000 steps.

Comment: Can you share the code of your training loop? Since it seems like disabling summaries solves the problem, it is likely that something in your training loop is adding nodes to the graph when summaries are enabled. One way to test this would be to add `tf.get_default_graph().finalize()` before the training loop, and see where the first exception is raised. To get steady performance, the best practice is to build the entire graph before starting the training loop, and not to add any nodes to the graph in the loop body.

Comment: It would be difficult for me to share the code. However `finalize()` does not generate any error during training. (I updated my question accordingly).